# Transfer out money with Stripe and PLAID ACH bank transfer

Tags: stripes, plaid

How can I transfer money from my Stripe account to my customers's bank account using PLAID and Stripe ACH? The provided documents by PLAID and Stripe are not clear enough. Can anyone give me a clear solution?

So far I have generated the stripe_bank_account_token according to stripe documentation. But after that how I can transfer money to the customer's bank account?

```
{
    "request_id": "uh55DrmrKb5rkr5",
    "stripe_bank_account_token": "btok_1OWXtwEHFDPRR065678033"
}
```

Comment: Give me a suggestion not a negative point unless you have any suggestions for me !!

Answer (score 1):

You once you have a bank account token, can create a charge using the Stripe Charges API:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create

You can also optionally associate the token with a customer using the Customers API:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-payment_method